# Mobile home interior finishing

Tags: finishing

I have a quick question. My parents just finished getting their double wide mobile home set, and opted out of the finish installation. (They did all but the finish drywall at the marriage line, and a couple of door frames). I am 100% comfortable doing the drywall, and the door frames, but want to make sure that it's done correctly first.

In looking, they provided extra wide laminated particle board 'filler strips' that go inside the door casings where the marriage line is. The thickness on both sides is varied. Meaning, it doesn't sit flush on both sides. It looks like one side needs to be scribed and cut so that it's even, however I have concerns with doing that because one side of the board will have wood exposed, while all other sides have the white laminate on them. Is this normal, or are we not installing these correctly?

Our original thought was that after you scribe it, you paint the end that's exposed and once the door trim is put on you won't notice it, but something seems off about that type of finish work. It seems 'hacky' and doesn't seem like something a contractor would normally do on a job site (especially since the scribe isn't always a straight cut and can lead to slightly jagged edges). We also attempted to pull back the laminate so we could 'rewrap' the exposed end once we trim it, but the laminate is glued and was tearing when trying to take it off.

I've never seen or done this type of finish work before (except the drywall), but once I understand how it's supposed to be done will have no problem doing it.

Any advice/help?

Comment: I haven’t done any modular homes other wiring the main. It sounds like the trim will cover the piece if it will I don’t understand the problem. A photo may help.

Comment: I'll try to get a photo tomorrow. The problem is that the trim doesn't completely cover it. Like most molding/trim it is offset about an 1/8 of an inch so at least an 1/8 of the cut edge of the board will be visible.